Bonding a metal screw into wood

I have refrigerator drawers with a custom wood facade. I need to install metal handles (2 screws) into the wood frame (3/8").
I cannot initiate the screws from the back of the wood to attach (screw in) the handles from the front. So I wanted to drill holes into the front of the wood and set the screws with handles into the wood using a high strength epoxy/glue.
Can I use an epoxy(into wood) to set the screws that are screwed into the handles that will go into the wood?
The pulling weight of the drawers is about 3 to 5lbs each time opening.

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I'm a little confused about what you want to do here so I think an edit to clarify is needed. Do I have it straight, you want to install the screws into the handles, then glue the projecting part of the screws into the wood? In case you haven't thought this through, would make the handles impossible to remove (without damaging the wood). "what's the strongest recommended epoxy to with stand opening and closing the drawers?" This is a shopping question which is not allowed on SE so I've edited it out.

Basically, the refrigerator drawers has a slide in panel of about a 1/4" and the frame casing is/was liquid/nailed to the panel and painted. They are new custom panel facades. In order to put the same handles on these drawers(5" two screw handles)I need to find a way to install the handles in its existing manner without destroying the panels and the handles able to handle continuous opening and closing. I thought drilling hole in panel and putting some sort of bonding in hole and pre-screwing the other end to the handles.

could you add a picture or two of a close up of the drawer at least 1 with it open to see the inside as well?

If you included a picture of the drawer pull, we might have a canny solution involving a tapped hole and a grub screw.

Can the custom wood facade be removed to gain access to the back of it?


Can I use an epoxy(into wood) to set the screws that are screwed into the handles that will go into the wood?

Yes, your proposed plan will work. However, it poses a potential issue for the long term in that this will permanently fix the handles in place.
You won't be able to remove the handles without damaging the wood1 should you ever want to or need to replace them, due to a change in taste, damage or simply due to wear which spoils the aesthetics.
Alternatively....
Instead I suggest you screw the screws into the wood2, remove the heads, and then epoxy into the handles.
This has the advantage that you should be able to separate the handles from the screws by heating the handles, since many/most epoxies soften considerably when heated.
You will need to drill out the threaded holes in the handles to a slightly larger size, to allow room for the epoxy. I would drill out just large enough that it eradicates the threading in the hole.
Choosing an epoxy
In either case you'll want to use a strong epoxy. There are a large number of epoxies available to the consumer that would be suitable.
As a general guide to knowing what to look for, the rule of thumb is that the longer an epoxy needs to set the stronger it is. It's more complex than that but you can trust that an epoxy which takes an hour to set is stronger than one which sets in only five minutes.
You can go a little further if you feel it's necessary by looking for a rating for tensile strength, expressed in PSI (pounds per square inch). Higher numbers are better. Note however you don't want an epoxy rated for high temperature if you want to retail removability as suggested above.

1 This damage could be quite severe, since it will tear some wood out from around the holes and might pull large flakes/chunks from the face, marring a considerable area of the wood. Such damage is repairable, but avoidable.
2 Into carefully-sized pilot holes, and being very careful not to drill too deep.
